# Why is UserDataSet being created twice by UserState?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I implemented a Chatbot with MS Botframework v4. I use UserState and ConversationState and my MemoryStorage is a BlobDB from Azure.

When I run my bot, I get two datasets for the UserState and only one for ConversationState.

At some point in my dialogs, the Bot seems to "switch" to another UserState dataset and everything previously saved in the old set is not accessible anymore.

This happens pretty early in in the conversation.

This is my onTurn. Here I access UserState and ConversationState for the first time:

```js
async onTurn(turnContext) {

        const dc = await this.dialogSet.createContext(turnContext);

        //await logMessageText(this.memoryStorage, turnContext, this.userState);

        // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
        if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.value){
            console.log(turnContext.activity.type.value);
        }

        if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {          
            // Continue ongoing dialog
            await dc.continueDialog();
        } else if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate) {
            // Do we have any new members added to the conversation?
            if (turnContext.activity.membersAdded.length !== 0) {
                // Iterate over all new members added to the conversation
                for (var idx in turnContext.activity.membersAdded) {
                    // Greet anyone that was not the target (recipient) of this message.
                    // Since the bot is the recipient for events from the channel,
                    // context.activity.membersAdded === context.activity.recipient.Id indicates the
                    // bot was added to the conversation, and the opposite indicates this is a user.
                    if (turnContext.activity.membersAdded[idx].id !== turnContext.activity.recipient.id) {


                        // Funktionierender Code, wenn WebChat gefixt
                        console.log("User added");

                        // Read ConversationData from State
                        const conversationData = await this.conversationDataAccessor.get(turnContext, {});
                        const user = await this.userDataAccessor.get(turnContext, {});


                        // Get userID which is either IDA for advisory or IDR for result
                        conversationData.URLparam = turnContext.activity.membersAdded[idx].id;

                        // Manually set userId for Emulator use
                        conversationData.URLparam = "1234A";


                        // Set userID
                        if (!conversationData.userID) {
                            console.log("UserID wird eingetragen");
                            conversationData.userID = conversationData.URLparam.substring(0, conversationData.URLparam.length-1);
                            console.log("Eingetragene user ID:" + conversationData.userID);
                        }

                        // Get last character which determines mode
                        conversationData.mode = conversationData.URLparam.substring(conversationData.URLparam.length-1, conversationData.URLparam.length);

                        // Write user and conversationdata to State
                        await this.conversationDataAccessor.set(turnContext, conversationData);
                        await this.userDataAccessor.set(turnContext, user);


                        // Route to correct dialog depending on treatment and bot type
                        if (treatment.initiation == true && conversationData.mode.localeCompare("A") == 0) {
                            console.log("Advisory Modus");
                            await dc.beginDialog('welcome', conversationData.userID);
                        } else if (treatment.initiation == false) {
                            await dc.beginDialog('startBot', conversationData.userID);
                        } else if (treatment.initiation == true && conversationData.mode.localeCompare("R") == 0) {
                            console.log("Result Modus");
                            await dc.beginDialog('investmentResult', conversationData.userID)
                        }
                    }
                    if (turnContext.activity.membersAdded[idx].id === turnContext.activity.recipient.id) {
                        // Start the dialog.
                        console.log("Bot joined");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My first dialog 'welcome' and then 'promptForName' is called. Everything works fine in the next code snippet:

```js
// Function for welcoming user
    async welcomeUser (step) {
        console.log("Welcome User Dialog");

        // Get userId from onTurn()
        const userID = step.options;

        // Get conversation- and userData from bot state
        const conversationData = await this.conversationDataAccessor.get(step.context, {});
        const user = await this.userDataAccessor.get(step.context, {});


        console.log("User in welcome dialog");
        console.log(util.inspect(user, false, null, false ));

        console.log("conversationData from Middleware");
        console.log(util.inspect(conversationData, false, null, false ));


        // Write user and conversationdata to state
        await this.userDataAccessor.set(step.context, user);
        await this.conversationDataAccessor.set(step.context, conversationData);


        // Welcome the user
        if (treatment.introduction == true && treatment.rememberName == true && treatment.gender == true) {
            await sendWithDelay("Hallo und herzlich willkommen, ich bin **Charles**, dein persönlicher **Investmentberater**. Ich begleite dich durch den Beratungsprozess.", step);
        } else if (treatment.introduction == true && treatment.gender == false) {
            var msg = "Hallo und herzlich willkommen, ich bin ein **Robo-Advisor**. Ich begleite dich durch den Beratungsprozess.";
            await sendWithDelay(msg, step);
        } else if (treatment.introduction == false && treatment.selfReference == false && treatment.rememberName == false) {
            var msg = "Du wirst nun durch den Beratungsprozess begleitet.";
            await sendWithDelay(msg, step);
        }

        // Check if bot in testmode and route to dialogs
        if (testing == true) {
            // Start main dialog
            return await step.beginDialog('mainMenu', userID);
        } else {
            // Start Profilecreation
            return await step.beginDialog('createProfile', userID);
        }
    }

    // Functions for creating UserProfile 
        async promptForName (step) {
            console.log("Name Prompt");

            // Get userID from prior step and clear changes
            const userID = step.options;

            // Read UserData from State
            const user = await this.userDataAccessor.get(step.context, {});
            const conversationData = await this.conversationDataAccessor.get(step.context, {});

            // Save User- and Conversationdata to State
            await this.userDataAccessor.set(step.context, user);
            await this.conversationDataAccessor.set(step.context, conversationData);

            // Before prompting, check if value already exists
            if(!user.name){
                if (user.deleted == true) {

                        if (treatment.selfReference == true) {
                            var msg = "Ich stelle dir nun die gleichen Fragen erneut.";
                            await sendWithDelay(msg, step);
                        } else {
                            var msg = "Im folgenden nochmal die gleichen Fragen.";
                            await sendWithDelay(msg, step);
                        }
                } else {
                        if (treatment.selfReference == true) {
                            var msg = "Ich stelle dir nun ein paar Fragen, um deine wichtigsten Daten zu erfassen.";
                            await sendWithDelay(msg, step);
                        } else {
                            var msg = "Im folgenden ein paar Fragen, um deine wichtigsten Daten zu erfassen.";
                            await sendWithDelay(msg, step);
                        }

                }
                // Username doesn't exist --> Prompt
                await delay(userData.name.prompt, step).then(async function() { 
                    return await step.prompt(NAME_PROMPT, userData.name.prompt);
                });
            } else {
                return await step.next();
            }
        }
```

In the next snippet, where the user's reply is written to userData, suddenly a new dataSet is created.

```js
async promptForAge (step) {
            console.log("Age Prompt");

            // Get userID from prior step and clear changes
            var userID = step.options;

            // Get UserData from State
            const user = await this.userDataAccessor.get(step.context, {});

            console.log("User in age dialog");
            console.log(util.inspect(user, false, null, false ));



            // Before saving entry, check if it already exists
            if(!user.name) {

                user.name = step.result;

                // Write userData to State
                await this.userDataAccessor.set(step.context, user);


                // Notify user about his name being remembered
                if (treatment.rememberName == true) {
                    var msg = `Hallo **${user.name}**! Danke, dass du mir deinen Namen verraten hast. Ich werde ihn mir ab jetzt merken.`;
                    await sendWithDelay(msg, step);
                }
            }
            // Before prompting, check if value already exists
            if(!user.age) {
                await delay(userData.age.prompt, step).then(async function() { 
                    return await step.prompt(AGE_PROMPT, userData.age.prompt);
                });

            } else {
                return await step.next();
            }
        }
```

This is how the datasets look in my DB:

[image]

This is the content of the two user datasets:

The first one that is being created

```
{"id":"emulator%2Fusers%2Fdeb871a4-cbb9-4e3c-9fff-e9ed88f597f5","realId":"emulator/users/deb871a4-cbb9-4e3c-9fff-e9ed88f597f5/","document":{"userData":{},"eTag":"*"}}
```

The one that's being created once step.result is written to user.name:

```
{"id":"emulator%2Fusers%2Fr_72zsnsmmnp","realId":"emulator/users/r_72zsnsmmnp/","document":{"userData":{"name":"John Doe"},"eTag":"*"}}
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the class and constructor (and any related code) from your bot.js file, as well?

Comment: You can check my code here: https://github.com/FRANZKAFKA13/roboadvisoryBot

Comment: In bot.js, in most places you are reading/writing data from the db using "userDataAccessor". However, there are a few places where you use "memoryStorage" (ex. lines 1496, 1507, 1774, and 1782). Is this intentional? I would guess this is the source of the duplicate entries but it's hard to know with the size and complexity of the files.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into my code. This is intentional and not the source of duplicate entries. Since I need to give the dataset to another bot, I have to manually save the user dataset with a manually generated ID to be able to access it with another bot. Overall, I get 4 entries: 2 userState, 1 conversation state and my manually saved userstate. The manually saved user dataset is also saved in another container to keep it clean from the massive amount of automatically generated datasets by the stateaccessors.

Comment: So, is it the first two userStates where there is a duplicate being created?